# Filter a result from Sunspot Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I have a search that's working great for searching an address in a property listing. But I can't figure out how to then filter those results based on the values of a certain text field. Here is what I have:

```
search = Listing.search do
  fulltext attributes[:address] + " -'Off Market'"

  with(:field_BedsTotal).greater_than_or_equal_to attributes[:field_BedsTotal]
  with(:field_BathsFull).greater_than_or_equal_to attributes[:field_BathsFull]
end
```

So it's searching for the user inputed address (discarding any that are off market), and only returning results with beds and bath greater or equal to what the user selects.

But there is another field called "field_PropertySubType" that has "Condo" or "Single Family" as values. I have a checkbox that the user can check (attributes[:condo], attributes[:single_family]). How can I filter the search results by these values of field_PropertySubType? I'm guessing with facets but I can't find enough documentation to help for my particular scenario. I did add the field_PropertySubType field to my searchable list as text. But if I add it to "fulltext" it only adds to the results (like anything that matches address OR condo") instead of filtering them (matching address AND condo). Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Trying out facet, but not quite getting the syntax correct:

```
searchable do
    text :field_StreetNumber, :field_StreetName, :field_StreetSuffix, :field_City
    string :field_PropertySubType, :field_PropertyType
  end

  def self.filter(attributes)

    search = Listing.search do
      fulltext attributes[:address]
      facet :field_PropertySubType, exclude: with(:field_PropertySubType,"Single Family") if params[:single_family].present?
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being:

```
facet :field_PropertySubType, exclude: [with(:field_PropertySubType, "Single Family")]
```

The "with" just needed brackets around it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.. you will have to use [`facets`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Drilling-down-with-facets), something like the following

```
facet :field_PropertySubType, exclude: with(:field_PropertySubType, attributes[:field_PropertySubType]
```

However, you will have to index this field as `string` instead as `fulltext` doesn't support faceting.

**Update**

Because of your `if` statement, the facets are not created if the option is not selected..you need an `else` statement..

```
if params[:single_family].present?
  facet :field_PropertySubType, exclude: with(:field_PropertySubType,"Single Family")
else
  facet :field_PropertySubType
end
```

Comment: please see my edit above. Perhaps you can help further. I'm not getting the syntax quite right.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but it causes me to get a "SystemStackError (stack level too deep)" error. FYI I'm using ruby 2.3.1 and rails 5.0.0

Comment: I am pretty sure this error is due to some other code, probably in your model or somewhere, specially callbacks. Solr won't cause this sort of error. Sharing more relevant code and logs might help..

Comment: Just so I don't go down a rabbit hole here, is it really possible that this is an error elsewhere in my code when it works perfectly before adding the facet? I've been searching around the internet and found this https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/395, but when I click on the link to see the bug report, it asks for a log in, so I hit a wall.